# Subset of attractor

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

Let $(X,F)$ be some dynamical system where $X$ is a compact metric space and $F\colon X\to X$ is continuous. Let
$$
\operatorname{NW}(F):=\{x\in X: \text{for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ } \exists~n\geq 1: F^{n}(U)\cap U\neq\emptyset\}.
$$

Then
$$
\operatorname{NW}(F)\subset \bigcap_{n\geq 1}F^n(X)=:E.
$$

Does anyone know a reference, maybe with a proof?

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original version of the question asked about general topological spaces, so I'll state results in that setting. It is easy to come up with counterexamples for non-compact or non-Hausdorff spaces. I will argue that the answer is yes if $X$ is [regular Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_space) and $F$ is a [closed map.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps) This includes the case of compact metric spaces $X,$ since a continuous map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is closed.

---

For regular Hausdorff spaces $X,$ we can use a stronger property of nonwandering points:

> A point $x$ is nonwandering ($x\in NW(F)$) if and only of for all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and all $N\geq 0$ there exists $n>N$ such that $F^n(U)\cap U\neq\emptyset.$

This property clearly implies your property - just take $N=1.$

For the other direction, we can assume $x$ is not periodic because that is an easy case. By regularity there is an open neighbourhood $U'\ni x$ whose closure $\overline{U'}$ in contained in $U\setminus \{F(x),F^2(x),\dots,F^N(x)\}.$ Define $U''=U'\setminus \bigcup_{n=1}^N F^{-n}(\overline{U'}).$ This is an open set containing $x$ and we've ensured that $U''\cap F^{-n}(U'')=\emptyset$ for $n=1,\dots,N.$ By your definition of a nonwandering point there exists $n\geq 1$ with $U''\cap F^n(U'')\neq \emptyset,$ which means $U''\cap F^{-n}(U'')\neq \emptyset,$ which forces $n>N$ as required.

---

This stronger definition of a nonwandering point implies that for each $N\geq 1,$ every point $x\in U=X\setminus \overline{F^N(X)}$ is wandering: $F^n(U)\subseteq F^N(X)\subseteq X\setminus U$ for $n\geq N.$ This gives $NW(F)\subseteq\bigcap_{n\geq 1}\overline{F^n(X)}.$ If $F$ is a closed map then the sets $F^n(X)$ are already closed, so this simplifies to $NW(F)\subseteq\bigcap_{n\geq 1}F^n(X)=E.$

Comment: Is there some reference for this proof? I am just curious.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Ins't $\bigcap_{n\geq 1}F^n(X)$ a global attractor if $X$ is compact and $F$ continious and hence contains all $F$-invariant sets, in particular the set $NW(F)$ which is $F$-invariant?

Comment: @Rhjg: if you have more questions or want someone to check an alternate proof you'd get a better response by posting another math.stackexchange.com question

Comment: Ok. I was just interested whether I was thinking correctly. Of course your proof is very nice. But maybe one could argue shorter as I suggested.

Comment: @Rhjg: still no references, but I've broken down the argument into separate steps that might help you relate it to other results. The main step is relating your definition of $NW(F)$ to a common stronger definition.